# Why google candlestick fallingColor and risingColor are not working for this?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I am working on Google Visulization charts .

I am trying to draw candlestick charts with sample data , the issue i am facing is that the falling color and raising color are being represented in single color only

This is my code

```
var mydata = [['13-Oct',1109.95,1132,1097.95,1113.45],['14-Oct',1113.45,1117,1095.6,1101.15],['15-Oct',1116,1132,1092.1,1129.2],['16-Oct',1130,1182.4,1130,1170.3],['19-Oct',1174,1182.2,1144.5,1162.15]];

function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mydata, true);

  var options = {
      legend:'none',
      colors:['red','brown'],
      candlestick: {
           fallingColor:{ fill: "orange", strokeWidth:0.5,stroke:'black'},
           risingColor:{fill:"yellowgreen",strokeWidth:0.5,stroke:'black'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

and this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pdmpb9w1/7/

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: Check your data, I think that is where your problem is. See http://jsfiddle.net/pdmpb9w1/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kevin Brown said, the problem is with your data. Your data should be structured like so:

```
var mydata = [
    //category  start err  start     end       end err
    ['13-Oct',  1109.95,   1132,     1097.95,  1113.45],
    ['14-Oct',  1113.45,   1117,     1095.6,   1101.15],
    ['15-Oct',  1116,      1132,     1092.1,   1129.2],
    ['16-Oct',  1130,      1182.4,   1130,     1170.3],
    ['19-Oct',  1174,      1182.2,   1144.5,   1162.15]
];
```

As you can see, all the values in the `end` column are smaller than the values in the `start` column, so all the candlesticks are colored as though falling.

On top of that, all your `start err` values are smaller than your `start` value, so you're not seeing the error/tolerance line because its hidden behind the bar. Vice versa for the `end` values.

I have no idea how your data should be ordered, but if I had to guess it would be something like this:

```
var mydata = [
    // note the first two numbers are swapped with the second two
    ['13-Oct', 1097.95, 1113.45, 1109.95, 1132],
    ['14-Oct', 1095.6,  1101.15, 1113.45, 1117],
    ['15-Oct', 1092.1,  1129.2,  1116,    1132],
    ['16-Oct', 1130,    1170.3,  1130,    1182.4],
    ['19-Oct', 1144.5,  1162.15, 1174,    1182.2]
];
```

Which would render the following:

[image]

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ovog4njt/)